# Android Simple Date Format Gives Wrong Date & Time while fetching current date & time using calendar

Tags: android, date, time, calendar, simpledateformat

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String formattedDate = date.format(c.getTime());
SimpleDateFormat time24hrs = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String intime= time24hrs.format(c.getTime());
```

The Above code is used for getting the current date and time, the problem is it works well but some times gives wrong current date & time especially it returns previous date and time (wrong date & time)
out of 100% it gives 80% correct date and time and 20% gives wrong date and time.
I don't what is the bug or problem or misconception in the code.
Please Help me to fix this problem.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you test on device or emulator ?

Comment: check my ans   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543775/calendar-view-or-datepicker-always-returning-wrong-month-android/30543840#30543840

Comment: Yeah i checked in emulator it gave correct date and time..The problem is i don't know when it gives wrong date & time.. mostly it gives correct date & time only

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy, HH:mm");
String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Where you can have DateFormat patterns such as:

```
"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z" ---- 2001.07.04 AD at 12:08:56 PDT
"hh 'o''clock' a, zzzz" ----------- 12 o'clock PM, Pacific Daylight Time
"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"------- Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"------- 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700
"yyMMddHHmmssZ"-------------------- 010704120856-0700
"K:mm a, z" ----------------------- 0:08 PM, PDT
"h:mm a" -------------------------- 12:08 PM
"EEE, MMM d, ''yy" ---------------- Wed, Jul 4, '01
```

Comment: I want the date in the format of "MM/dd/yyyy"                                                       and time in 24hrs format

Answer (score 0):

To get time in 24hrs use `k`

```
SimpleDateFormat time24hrs = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
String intime= time24hrs.format(c.getTime());
```

Please refer this for Date format **symbol list** [Android Official Site - SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I need to separate the date and time.                                                            separate strings sent to .net web service                                             example                                                                                                date:"06/12/2015"                                                                              time:"14:35"